# Finding multiple records of the same person when the name cannot be trusted

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour

I have a list of 100 of events, and each event has a list of thousands of persons.

Some persons went to multiple events, and I would like to select all the events a person went to. I could just look for the name of the person in all the events, but the problem is that sometimes their name is written differently, and some persons have the same name (such as Kris Peeters, a common name in Belgium).

So I would like to use the other features of the persons lists (such as Age and City of the person) to make sure I am selecting always the exact same person. But Age and City are sometimes missing.

Which algorithm should I use to maximise the chance that I am selecting the same person?

(Very similar to this this question, but I am looking for a statistical approach:
https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/how-do-i-correctly-identify-an-individual-who-goes-by-multiple-names)

Comment: Hard to say with the limited info you presented. What other variables do you have besides age and city? Do you have geographic IDs of the places where the events happened, or are these events linked to the person data? For example, Kris Peeters may be a common name in Belgium, but it is reasonable to assume a Kris Peeters in the North of the country is likely not going to attend the event in the South. In situations like these, there's a general recipe, for "matching" the bulk of your people to the events, but you will probably need to eyeball the data and manually match at some point.